# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Vi and Vim breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          7
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           119        228
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               11         34
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         46         49
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               12         95
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               216        680
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               48        217
Tags merged                                       3          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          1
Tag synonyms created                              3          0
Questions unprotected                             1          0
Questions reopened                               15          1
Questions protected                               0          2
Questions migrated                                2          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0         36
Questions closed                                135         30
Question flags handled⁴                          23         13
Posts undeleted                                   5         29
Posts locked                                      0          4
Posts deleted⁵                                   63        367
Posts bumped                                      0        627
Comments undeleted                                4          0
Comments flagged                                  1        258
Comments deleted⁶                               230        570
Comment flags handled                           106        153
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                   1        101
Answer flags handled                             95          7
All comments on a post moved to chat              3          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...